# How to crack a 2-dimensional Linear Congruential Generator (LCG)?

Tags: linear-algebra, cryptography, random

The 2-dimensional LCG is defined as below:
$$
x_{i+2} = a\cdot x_{i} + b \cdot x_{x+1} + c \pmod{p}
$$

where $a, b, c$ and the module $p$ are unknown.

We are given 10 consecutive outputs. The problem is to recover the modulus $p$ and $a,b,c$.

The solution to the 1-dimensional LCG is first construct $z_i \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, and then calculate the gcd of $z_i$ to recover the modulus $p$.

However, in this 2-dimensional LCG case, it is hard to find something that equivlant to 0 (mod p).

We can first let $t_i = x_{i+1} - x_{i}$, where $t_{i+2} = a \cdot t_i + b \cdot t_{i+1}$.

Let $P_i = \begin{bmatrix}
t_{i+2} & t_{i+1}\\
t_{i+1} & t_{i}
\end{bmatrix}$, $A = \begin{bmatrix}
b & a\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$, then we have $P_{i+1} = A\cdot P_{i}$.

However, $P_{i+2} \cdot P_{i} - P_{i+1}^2 = A^2 \cdot P_i -  A \cdot P_i \cdot A \cdot P_i \neq 0$ (mod p).

And I stuck here.

Is there any other methods that can solve this problem?